# Counterexample to the converse that the image of a continuous function on a sequentially compact set is sequentially compact.

Tags: real-analysis

We know that if a function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous and $A$ is a sequentially compact set, then the image $f(A)$ is sequentially compact. What I have to show is that the converse is not necessarily true.

I think the function $f: A=\{(x,y):|x| \leq3 \}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=x$ does the job, but I'm still a bit unsure. The function is clearly continuous, the set $f(A)$ is sequentially compact, but the preimage, $A$, is not sequentially compact, right?

Comment: What exactly is your converse statement? Is it "if $f(A)$ is sequentially compact then $A$ is", while $f$ is assumed continuous throughout? If that's the case, your example works just fine.

Comment: Yes, that is the converse I'm trying to disprove. Thanks for the reassurance.